# Kubernetes Ingress Enable Http2

Tags: http, kubernetes, bazel

I have a k8s deployment on an azure cluster, connected to a service, exposed via an ingress like below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: infrastructure--buildfarm
  name: buildfarm-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-internal
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: selfsigned-cluster-issuer
spec:
  rules:
  - host: buildfarm.dev.azr.internal.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: aks-buildfarm
          servicePort: 8980
        path: /(.*)
```

I'm trying to execute a simple build using the bazel buildfarm API for bazel, but end up with the following error:

```
eito@fuji:~/MyRepo$ bazel --client_debug build //examples/... --remote_executor=grpcs://buildfarm.azr.internal.mydomain.com/
[INFO 17:07:22.373 src/main/cpp/option_processor.cc:407] Looking for the following rc files: /etc/bazel.bazelrc,/home/eito/MyRepo/.bazelrc,/home/eito/.bazelrc
[INFO 17:07:22.373 src/main/cpp/rc_file.cc:56] Parsing the RcFile /home/eito/MyRepo/.bazelrc
[INFO 17:07:22.373 src/main/cpp/rc_file.cc:56] Parsing the RcFile user.bazelrc
[INFO 17:07:22.373 src/main/cpp/rc_file.cc:129] Skipped optional import of user.bazelrc, the specified rc file either does not exist or is not readable.
[INFO 17:07:22.373 src/main/cpp/rc_file.cc:56] Parsing the RcFile /home/eito/.bazelrc
[INFO 17:07:22.374 src/main/cpp/blaze.cc:1626] Debug logging requested, sending all client log statements to stderr
[INFO 17:07:22.374 src/main/cpp/blaze.cc:1509] Acquired the client lock, waited 0 milliseconds
[INFO 17:07:22.376 src/main/cpp/blaze.cc:1697] Trying to connect to server (timeout: 30 secs)...
[INFO 17:07:22.381 src/main/cpp/blaze.cc:1264] Connected (server pid=240772).
[INFO 17:07:22.381 src/main/cpp/blaze.cc:1974] Releasing client lock, let the server manage concurrent requests.
INFO: Invocation ID: d00bb07c-440c-4220-a04a-74cb54ef9913
ERROR: Failed to query remote execution capabilities: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: HTTP status code 0
invalid content-type: null
headers: Metadata(:status=000,date=Fri, 01 Oct 2021 16:07:26 GMT,strict-transport-security=max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains)
DATA-----------------------------
��� 
DATA-----------------------------
h���Unexpected HTTP/1.x request: POST /build.bazel.remote.execution.v2.Capabilities/GetCapabilities 
DATA-----------------------------

[INFO 17:07:26.261 src/main/cpp/blaze.cc:2093] failure_detail: message: "Failed to query remote execution capabilities: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: HTTP status code 0\ninvalid content-type: null\nheaders: Metadata(:status=000,date=Fri, 01 Oct 2021 16:07:26 GMT,strict-transport-security=max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains)\nDATA-----------------------------\n\000\000\022\004\000\000\000\000\000\000\003\177\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275\000\334\000\020\000\000\000\006\000\000 \000\000\000\004\010\000\000\000\000\000\000\019\000\001\nDATA-----------------------------\n\000\000h\007\000\000\000\000\000\177\357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275\000\000\000\001Unexpected HTTP/1.x request: POST /build.bazel.remote.execution.v2.Capabilities/GetCapabilities \nDATA-----------------------------\n"
remote_execution {
  code: CAPABILITIES_QUERY_FAILURE
}
```

I've asked on their slack, and was told I need to use HTTP2 for my ingress, since the error implies I am trying to convert HTTP1->HTTP2. How could I modify my ingress so it uses HTTP2?

I've looked around https://developer-docs.citrix.com/projects/citrix-k8s-ingress-controller/en/latest/how-to/http-use-cases/#http2-upgrade
and saw that it requires re-configuration of our nginx controller?

Is there an easier way of doing this instead of taking a deep dive with the nginx controllers? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Which exact `ingress` is installed? Different ingress controllers have different annotations. Your link is about citrix ingress controller. Adding annotation thought is not difficult at all, the thing is to add correct annotation so it will be recognized.

Comment: Thanks! It's solved now